# Does a lens exist that is parfocal, has a linear zoom throw, and is affordable?

Tags: lens, dslr, zoom, optics

I'm working on a project to create, essentially, a servo-powered zoom lens, using a (D)SLR zoom, a zoom ring gear, and a stepper motor. After mounting the zoom ring gear, I'll attach a pinion gear to the stepper motor shaft to control the motion of the zoom ring.

[ENG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_news-gathering)/cine-style servo lenses that do this by design usually feature:

- **[Parfocal optics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parfocal_lens)** This means that the lens holds focus through the entire zoom range; a videographer can zoom into a subject, focus, and then zoom back out without needing to adjust focus. Most modern (D)SLR lenses aren't parfocal (they're [varifocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varifocal_lens)) because they don't need to be (autofocus and still photography obviate the need to hold focus), and that makes them simpler, cheaper, and lighter.
- **Linear zoom throw.** As you move the zoom ring on many (D)SLR lenses, the field of view doesn't change linearly. Through some focal length ranges, the field of view changes at a different rate than it does through others. A linear zoom throw allows for smooth, consistent zooming that doesn't draw attention to itself.
- **Constant aperture.** The lens doesn't necessarily need to have a fixed aperture, but it needs to hold a constant aperture through the zoom range so that the image doesn't darken while zooming in.
- **High price tag.** This is mainly why I'm working on an alternative solution, though I also prefer the additional control that I'll have over a stepper motor in experimental shoots.

With that in mind, I want to find a (D)SLR lens to act as a budget alternative to a servo lens. It would need to have:

1. parfocal optics
2. linear zoom throw
3. constant aperture
4. full frame 35mm coverage
5. a mount that can be adapted to Sony E-Mount (on an [a7S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_A7)) - fortunately, most mounts can
6. the longer the zoom range, the better (ideally, at least a 2×)
7. affordable price

I define "affordable" as somewhere in the ballpark of $300-1800 for a new or good used copy. Below that, it's probably not of very good quality; much above that, and I might as well just buy this and call it a day:

http://www.sony.com/electronics/camera-lenses/selp28135g

Weight, brand and speed aren't as important to me, as long as it's not of poor quality. I also don't need auto aperture or focus.

Does such a lens exist, or is this a pipe dream?

I've found [various](http://nikonrumors.com/forum/topic.php?id=5175) [lists](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/16833661) of (D)SLR lenses that are supposedly parfocal, but I don't know if they meet or approach these other criteria; I can (and will) research everything but the linearity of the zoom throw, since that's not at all a commonly-listed specification. I guess I'm mainly interested to know if anyone has experience with any lens(es) that they know to be parfocal, and can confirm that they have a linear zoom throw.

Comment: If you're using a stepper motor to control the zoom, there's probably a micro controller somewhere in the mix. If that's the case, then you should be able to easily accommodate non-linear zooms simply by programming the controller to vary the zoom rate.

Comment: @Caleb: Thanks - I've considered that, and it's certainly possible, but I don't think "easily" is quite accurate. ;-) It adds another layer of complexity. I would need to discover - either through research or (more likely) experimentation - the actual behavior of the zoom throw, which can be complex. I'd need to accommodate that in my code to linearize the throw while simultaneously applying easing if/when needed. It's an option to keep on the table if I find a lens that satisfies every requirement but that one, but it would save a lot of time to be able to avoid that approach altogether.

Comment: Parfocal, linear zoom throw, constant aperture, etc. OR affordable. You have to choose one or the other, but you can't have both.

Comment: Michael Clark, I don't believe that yet. Sounds nice, but I need evidence. For example, the Canon 17-40mm f/4 L (<$500 used) has most of what I'm looking for, but I haven't verified the linear zoom throw (just one anecdotal report), the focal range isn't very large and it has major distortion issues esp. wide, so I haven't sprung for a copy yet. There is a ton of affordable old Canon FD, Minolta MD, Pentax K, etc. glass out there from back in the MF days when "parfocality" was more of a design concern. Can you honestly dismiss every single one of those lenses? Keep in mind $1800 isn't peanuts.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I've not yet seen a single modern SLR zoom lens that *isn't* parfocal through the zoom range (someone please correct me if I'm wrong here). One other thing of note (especially if AF isn't required) is that a few of the *one-touch* zooms from the 1980s/90s might meet your criteria. I'm thinking of lenses like the 75-150mm f/3.5 Nikon E-series zoom. Although it is only a medium tele 2x zoom, it is constant aperture, cheap and has excellent optical characteristics.

Comment: Thanks, @HamishKL - unfortunately, that's not the case; most modern (D)SLR zooms are varifocal, though the focus doesn't drift a large amount, so they may seem parfocal at first glance. Even a few of the ones on the lists I linked to in my question have been "disproven" by the community of lens owners. Strangely, manufacturers aren't typically forthcoming about whether their (D)SLR lenses are parfocal unless they're specifically designed/marketed as video, ENG or cine lenses. Most are discovered by user testing.

Comment: Also, @HamishKL - w/r/t your recommendation, you're definitely in the right ballpark. I just received this lens on Monday: http://www.kenrockwell.com/nikon/35-70mm-35-ais.htm - it's a great lens, but unfortunately the zoom throw turned out to be far from linear. That's actually what prompted this question. I could buy up old zooms all day and test them myself, but by the time I find the "right" one, I'll have exceeded my budget. The 75-150mm you mentioned is indeed a great lens, but the one-touch operation would require a different (and more difficult) control mechanism than a zoom gear.

Comment: @Bungle - Thanks for clarifying the not-quite-parfocal thing. I'd suspected that might be the case but the focus drift while zooming really isn't visible in normal photography. I'm sure astrophotographers would disagree here though. As for one touch zooms (Nikon also made a 100-300mm f/5.6), could you not use a screw drive to slowly and smoothly zoom, with the front lens barrel loosely held captive by a C clip at front and back, while your focus motor could apply rotational friction torque to the finger grip of the same barrel? This way your whole motor mechanism could remain stationary.

Comment: @HamishKL astrophotographers tend to primes.  They're a few stops faster (the difference between a minute exposure and 15 seconds is substantial on a dSLR... or an hour vs. 15 minutes for a single film exposure) and sharper. The zoom doesn't give you anything.  Either you're doing wide field (where the 24, 28, 35 and 50 are quite adequate), a long lens on a camera, or hooking the camera up to a telescope (in which case its another story all together).  Zooms don't enter the equation very often.  And the focus is always at infinity.

Comment: Sure, but even astrophotogrphers have to start somewhere, and that woefully inadequate one-touch Soligor 80-200mm zoom with a piece of tape holding it at 200mm might be all you have at the time. :). Anyhow, my point is that the two one touch zooms I mentioned meet all of your criteria except point 5.

Comment: @HamishKL, are you sure about that though? They're great values for sure, but I haven't found any evidence that they're parfocal or have a linear zoom throw. Albeit based on my (limited) understanding of lens design, I don't believe the push/pull mechanism necessarily implies either one. They do meet #5, BTW. Also, thanks for the screw drive idea; I think I can picture what you're saying, and it's worth investigating. I'm still not apt to integrate a focus motor (which only makes things simpler) but I might try to pick up a cheap copy to test and experiment.

Comment: @Bungle - Well, I own both lenses and can confirm that the zoom action directly and linearly moves the middle lens group, with no cams or other mechanisms involved in translating the longitudinal movement of the outer lens barrel to the inner lens group movement. As for parfocality (wow, that really *is* a word), I can only say that I see no variation in focus between zoomed shots, even when magnifying the images. If you'd like me to confirm this more accurately, I can take a look through my lens collimator.

Comment: It also occurs to me that from a mechanical perspective you possibly want a lens with a long-ish focus throw (which both of these Nikon lenses have), so that any play in the mechanism(s) doesn't have a large effect on focus accuracy. Some of the AF lenses have ridiculously short focus throw, making accurate focusing tricky. Longer focus throw = more rotations and therefore slower focusing however.

Answer (score 5):

This reply to @Caleb's comment kept growing and growing into an off-topic answer. Maybe you still find it useful.

---

> After mounting the zoom ring gear, I'll attach a pinion gear to the **stepper motor shaft to control the motion of the zoom ring.**

> A linear zoom throw allows for **smooth, consistent zooming** that doesn't draw attention to itself.

"stepper motor" and "smooth" don't go together well.

Stepper motors make steps (hence the name ;)) and never a continuous motion. There's no way around the fact that the torque (which is the thing that causes the motion) is applied in discontinuous steps. You can smooth the motion with various efforts to some degree, but such efforts take away the inherent advantage of the stepper motor: its simplicity. And even if you manage to smooth out the motion to a desirable degree, you basically created a regular motor, so why not use that in the first place?

Take a look at the various stabilising gimbals. They often use brushless motors. What would the footage look like if they used a ste-ep-ep-ep-epper motor instead?

And should you ever want to turn the motor driver off to allow manual rotation of the zoom ring, you'd always have to disengage the gear that connects the stepper motor mechanically to the lens, because the steps of a stepper motor are noticeable when rotating it by hand.

I don't like to be *that* guy, but to some degree your question reads like this:

> There are these expensive lenses that have the properties A, B and C which all make them expensive to manufacture. Now I'd like to duct tape a stepper motor to a lens with the same properties and have it for cheap. Any ideas how?

I'm not seeing how merely requiring the existence of the same properties of an expensive lens enables you to build a cheap one.

> It adds another layer of complexity.  I would need to discover - either through research or (more likely) experimentation - the actual behavior of the zoom throw, which can be complex.

Chances are that lens companies do actually do some research and development. I'm afraid now it's your turn. You have some engineering to do that goes beyond "I just buy components that happen to full fill all my requirements".

> I also don't need auto [...] focus

I think you do want auto focus, though, but not for auto focus in the classical sense. That's because automation of both zoom and focus enables you to control either one, but also both at the same time, depending on each other.

When you calibrate a lens, you obtain knowledge about how

- focus changes, depending on focal length (varifocus)
- zoom changes, depending on zoom ring rotation (nonlinearity of the ring)

Knowing these static errors, you can compensate for them during operation. As suggested by @Caleb in a comment, you can compensate the nonlinear zoom ring pretty much directly.

In order to turn the varifocal lens into a parfocal one, you'd have to automatically adjust the focus depending on the current focal length (and the relationship between them obtained during calibration).

If you did the inverse (adjusting focal length according to focus), that would prevent any focus breathing the lens might have.

In conclusion:

1. With the ability to rotate and measure the position of both zoom and
   focus ring on a lens automatically, the hardware becomes general
   purpose and applicable to (pretty much) any lens.
2. Both requirements (parfocal lens, linear zoom throw) are abstracted away from the lens itself and are now a job of your software that controls the two rings, which allows you to use lenses that are neither parfocal nor have a linear zoom throw and thus cheap.
3. Given that the lenses deviate from the original requirements in a static manner, they can be calibrated. That means that the software that controls the automated rings of the lens is also universal and all that needs to change in order to use a different lens is to use a different calibration.

By making parfocality<sup>1</sup> of the lens and linearity of its zoom a property of the system surrounding the lens, the lens does not have to have these properties any more, which enables you to use plenty of other (cheaper) lenses.

---

<sup>1</sup> that's totally a word

Comment: "parfocality" – it's a perfectly cromulent word.

Comment: Sorry, multi-comment response inbound here, but I don't know of a better format.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I sincerely appreciate you taking the time to think it through. It is useful, but also more than a little patronizing. I do understand that stepper motors have limitations inherent to their design, that I have some engineering ahead of me (that's kind of the point), that lens companies do R&D, and that the cost of said R&D is amortized in the price of the resulting lenses they release.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the cynicism that's evident in your answer is all your own. If I wanted to join in, I could just as easily characterize your answer as reading like "So you don't want to pay big money for a lens that already does all of this. You want something for nothing. Easy, just start with a lens that does none of this, spend a ton of time engineering those features back into the lens, and voila."

Comment: I'm looking for a lens that's somewhere in the middle of two extremes we've now characterized: one that has most of the features I want, none of the features I don't need, and thus a price that's more friendly to my budget than $2500. I'll then spend a limited amount of time building in the feature that I want to control even more than the $2500 solution allows (i.e., motion control of the zoom ring) while spending as little time as possible reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, stepper motors are by design not smooth, but I've never attached one to the zoom ring of a lens. (If you have and it led to unacceptable results, please let me know the details.) I'll probably start by not attaching it with duct tape. Then, I'll choose a motor with a high step count, use a library that facilitates microstepping, and hopefully end up with a degree of smoothness that is within the tolerances of play in a typical zoom ring cam (plus gear backlash of the outer ring). My theory is that it will be smooth enough that the discrete steps of the motor won't be visible in video.

Comment: Will it all work? No idea. But I'd just like to clarify that I'm doing this to create a new tool for experimentation, learn a bit more about lenses, optics, and motor control, and have fun in the process. I'm not just a miser. With lens designs being reused, adapted, copied, etc., in the industry, I think it's not unreasonable to think that maybe there's a good deal on a lens out there that offers most of what I need that could be "hacked" for my own purposes.

Comment: @Bungle a big part of why DIY projects are often cheap is because the labour is free. Reinventing the wheel might have a lower cost than buying one. You have to find out how to control a lens ring with a motor anyway. You can apply a lot of that knowledge to control the focus ring, too and get yourself rid of the parfocal requirement. Maybe in a second development step. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @null. My point is that there's still a very substantial difference in LOE between moving the zoom ring linearly or with a standard easing function, vs. trying to zero out focus drift across the entire zoom range. I'm a software developer, film major and I've done stepper motor projects before, so I know a bit about this. I'm more than willing to pay for "parfocality" if it's an option within my budget. If it's not, then it's probably not worth my time to try to engineer it out of a lens.